# gmake all permission denied on fedora core 3 - Nachos project

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, nachos

I'm working on a `nachOS` project in **Operating System Course**. What I'm facing here is that I ran terminal with admin privilege but still **got permission denied error** when **trying to build** `nachOS` again (first time was ok, second time was when I added a `createfile` function) using `gmakeall`. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP8RH.png) is a screenshot of the error.

Comment: Fedora Core 3 is more than 10 years old and more than 10 years unsupported. You should really use something more recent ([now we have Fedora 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29#Releases))

Comment: I was wondering if it was a typo, forgetting the 2 in front of 3, instead after looking at the screenshot..... thanks for reviving such good memories.